# Add custom properties to Excel workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

With VBA, I can edit arbitrary workbook metadata like so, and it will be reflected on SharePoint:

```
With ThisWorkbook
        .ContentTypeProperties("Property A") = 1
        .ContentTypeProperties("Prop B") = “Something”
End With
```

Now, I am hoping to do the same with `openpyxl`

I can do this for properties without spaces:

```
wb.properties.title = 'test'
```

but properties with spaces won't work--I try this and the script runs, but nothing shows on SharePoint:

```
setattr(wb.properties, 'Project Title', 'hello')
wb.properties.__dict__['Project Number'] =  '12'
```

This can be done with `xlsxwriter`

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(wb_path)
workbook.set_custom_property('Project Title', 'hello')
workbook.close()
```

but it will create a new workbook...

According to this https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/merge_requests/384/diffs?commit_id=e00ce36aa92ae4fffa7014e460a8999681d73b8b

I could simply do

`wb.custom_doc_props.add(k, v)`, but I'm getting `no attribute custom_doc_props` with the latest version (I believe), `3.0.10`.

I installed the 3.2.0b1 version with pip, and now get `AttributeError: 'CustomDocumentPropertyList' object has no attribute 'add'`. I guess the method isn't fully implemented yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with version 3.1.0 of `openpyxl`. You can download via `pip` with

```
python -m pip install https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/archive/branch/3.1/openpyxl-branch-3.1.zip
```

and assign properties like so

```
from openpyxl.packaging.custom import (
    BoolProperty,
    DateTimeProperty,
    FloatProperty,
    IntProperty,
    LinkProperty,
    StringProperty,
    CustomPropertyList,
)



props = CustomPropertyList()
props.append(StringProperty(name='hello world', value='foo bar'))
wb.custom_doc_props = props
wb.save(...)
```

Data is preserved on SharePoint. More info here: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/doc/workbook_custom_doc_props.rst